# What's the best way to use OpenGL with Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opengl

I've been trying to create a Cocoa project that uses OpenGL. `NSOpenGLView` is too restrictive for my needs, so I've created my own custom `NSView` subclass. I need to have multiple copies of this class on screen at once. And I need to use shaders.

What's the best way to organize this sort of project? I've tried a ton of different setups, but I always seem to wind up having invalid drawables, GL errors, trouble managing contexts, etc. Is there a simple way that I'm overlooking? Maybe setting up a single context at app launch and having all views share it?

Comment: what are you trying to do with OpenGL ?

Comment: `NSOpenGLView` was the simplest for me. What was the problem with it?

Comment: It had the same sorts of invalid drawable, GL error issues that my custom view does, only I couldn't tinker with it to fix them. :) I'm trying to make a cross-platform game and I just want to ensure that the Mac side of things is using OpenGL the way it's meant to. I don't want to use SDL or something to set up my GL view for a Mac app.

Comment: I suggest you put the time in to learn how to use NSOpenGLView correctly.  It properly handles the issues of making a GL context exist within the cocoa view hierarchy, and rolling  your own replacement is more work than you realize, as you're currently finding out.

Answer (score -5):

Stay away from messing with OpenGL yourself...it sucks. Just say no.

I HIGHLY recommend using Cocos2D. Its a FANTASTIC graphics library that is highly supported and documented and handles all the OpenGL nonsense and makes the pain go away. Don't touch OpenGL unless you want to spend more time dinking with technical details than actually making your project happen.

Comment: And yet I have no trouble using OpenGL for the Linux version of the app. It's just the setup and management of contexts that seems incredibly complicated on OS X comparatively, probably because of all the structure surrounding NSView.

Comment: This is a rant, not an answer.  There are many perfectly viable reasons for dealing with OpenGL directly, rather than through a wrapper framework.  Also, cocos2d, as good as it is, is not a solution for 3-D graphics.